# _Pass_fn : where is the constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, predicate

```
template<class _Fn,
    enable_if_t<!_Pass_functor_by_value_v<_Fn>, int> = 0>
    constexpr _Ref_fn<_Fn> _Pass_fn(_Fn& _Val)
    {   // pass functor by "reference"
    return {_Val};
    }
```

The function `_Pass_fn` return the object `_Ref_fn<_Fn>`, but the `_Ref_fn` has no constructor which accepts one argument.

```
template<class _Fx>
    struct _Ref_fn
    {   // pass function object by value as a reference
    template<class... _Args>
        constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(_Args&&... _Vals)
        {   // forward function call operator
        return (_Fn(_STD forward<_Args>(_Vals)...));
        }

    _Fx& _Fn;
    };
```

How does this work?

Comment: This is called aggregate initialization.

Comment: Note that most of the names in this code begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter, so are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of [Aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

It is ok to brace-initialize simple structs with members values without defining constructor:

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
...
Point p{1,2};
```